# set functions and relations

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This might be a very basic question, but I hope you can help.

Given a (total) function $f\colon \wp(X) \rightarrow \wp(Y)$ under what condition does there exists a relation $g \subseteq X \times Y$ such that the image of $g[A] = f(A)$ whenever $A \in \wp(X)$?

Is it enough to request distributivity, i.e., $f(A \cup B) =f(A) \cup f(B)$ whenever $A,B\in \wp(X)$ ? or do I need something more/else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessary conditions must be (for any $A,A_t\in\wp(X)$ and $B,B_t\in\wp(Y)$, where $t, t_1, t_2\in T$, $T$ an index set):
$$f(\cup_t A_t)=\cup_t f(A_t)\tag{1}$$
$$f^{-1}(\cup_t B_t)=\cup_t f^{-1}(B_t)\tag{2}$$
$$f(\cap_t A_t)\subseteq\cap_t f(A_t)\tag{3}$$
$$f^{-1}(\cap_t B_t)\subseteq\cap_t f^{-1}(B_t)\tag{4}$$
$$f(A_{t_1}\setminus A_{t_2})\subseteq f(A_{t_1})\setminus f(A_{t_2}\tag{3a})$$
$$f^{-1}(B_{t_1}\setminus B_{t_2})\subseteq f^{-1}(B_{t_1})\setminus f^{-1}(B_{t_2}\tag{4a})$$
$$A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))\tag{5}$$
$$B\subseteq f(f^{-1}(B))\tag{6}$$

($(3a)$ and $(4a)$ are consequence of $(3)$ and $(4)$ respectively)

Sufficiency of $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$ must be proved.

Comment: thank you! That's super nice.

Answer (score 1):

Union preservation guarantees only that $f^{-1}(A\cup B)\subset f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$ for any $A, B\in \wp(Y)$ while it is $g^{-1}[A\cup B]=g^{-1}[A]\cup g^{-1}[B]$

So it must be imposed the inverse preservation of the union as well.

$$f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$$

Comment: That is nicely spotted. Let me give it a thought ..

Comment: Hmm .. would I also need to have something similar for the intersection ($f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(A_i)$ )?

Comment: yes, mine was a hint. There are possibly other conditions as well to be considered for a sufficient condition, not only this last you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

What you give is not sufficient. Consider the mapping $f: \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathcal P(\{*\})$, such that
$$
f(A) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb \{*\} &\text{if $A$ is infinite}\\
\emptyset & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$ for all $A, B \subseteq \mathbb N$: if both $A,B$ are finite, then both sides of the equation are $\emptyset$, while if at least one is infinite, then both sides of the equation are $\{*\}$. However, there is no relation $g$, for if $g = \emptyset$, then trivially $g[\mathbb N] = \emptyset \neq \{*\} = f(\mathbb N)$; while if $g \neq \emptyset$, then $(x,*) \in g$, so that $g[\{x\}] = \{*\} \neq \emptyset = f(\{x\})$.

A sufficient condition on $f$ would be that $f$ distributes over all unions, so that
$$
f\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right) = \bigcup_{i \in I} f(A_i)
$$
for all $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$. In that case, we can define
$$
g = \{(x,y) \in X \times Y \mid y \in f(\{x\})\}.
$$
Then for each $A$, we have that
$$
f(A) = f\left( \bigcup_{x \in A} \{x\}\right) = \bigcup_{x \in X} f(\{x\}) = \bigcup_{x\in X}g[\{x\}] = g[X].
$$
Note that this is a very strong condition on $f$, and perhaps a weaker nice condition might be available.

Comment: thanks! Yes, that is some condition. Hmmm .. I actually have the special case where $f(A) \neq \emptyset$ whenever $A\in \wp(X)$. That avoids the suggested case, but perhaps not the issue?

Comment: @Kirkeby, no, it is not. Take a two-element set $\{a, b\}$ instead of $\{*\}$, and let finite sets map to $\{a\}$ while infinite sets map to $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Again thanks. I've finally got the argument. That is really clever. In some way, it seems related to the relation properties of images and preimages: Image and Preimage of union and intersection under Relation [A proof wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Image_of_Intersection_under_Relation) -any thoughts?